# Xcode parse issue on UIAlertView's cancelButtonTitle - "Expected ']'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

Here is my code and the screenshot below:

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" 
delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

[image]

I'm getting a strange error on Xcode 5.

Anyone ever encountered such an error? 
I'm using Cocoapods and including few libs in my project. Maybe it has something to do with it?

Comment: Remove the extraneous `,` after `otherButtonTitles:`.

Comment: No offense. but i think read the code carefully to find the extra comma is slightly faster than post here...

Comment: Guys thanks for the answers, but the comma is not the reason of this issue. Missing the comma was my mistake, but it has nothing to do with the error... (and why it would highlight the cancelButtonTitle if I missed the comma after otherButtonTitles anyway?! ) See the new pic in my answer.

Comment: @iDavid Edit your questions instead of posting edits as answers.

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan and sorry for that, I already did!

Comment: Product -> Perform Action -> Preprocess. Find the code there. Does the preprocessed code seem okey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable reason is an invisible invalid character somewhere in your code, probably between `nil` and `cancelButtonTitle`.

Remove the two lines entirely and write them again.

The second possibility is doing something really bad with macros, e.g defining a macro

```
#define cancelButtonTitle @"Cancel"
```

There is a reason why all macros should be written in uppercase letters:

```
#define CANCEL_BUTTON_TITLE @"Cancel"
```

And it would be even better not using macros for string constants.

Comment: I did many times. I let the Xcode to generate with auto-completion. No help. I've tried to post in other classes.. the same error. It has something to do with the word "cancel" during the compilation.

Comment: @iDavid Are you using macros? Could you show us your preprocessed code? Is there something similar to `#define cancel ...` or `#define cancelButton ...`?

Comment: There you go! I cant believe I have a macro exactly called cancelButtonTitle . Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Will add my comments into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the comma after otherbuttonTitles: you just need `otherButtonTitles:nil];`

Comment: Read my answer please, the comma is not the reason of this issue. the parsing issue is still there without the comma!